# Simultaneously write to a file from multiple processes

Tags: c#, filestream

```
                using (var stream = new FileStream(
                    this.filePath,
                    FileMode.Append,
                    FileAccess.Write,
                    FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        writer.Write("A randomly generated string from process X thread Y");
                        writer.Flush();
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                }
```

I am basically using this piece of code in 2 test methods in 2 different Visual Studios (different solutions).  I'm running 2 threads per test for 1000 calls to this.

However, when I execute this, all the lines from whichever test I executed first get written to the file, and THEN all the lines get written to the file by the other process.  I thought that the `writer.Flush()` and `stream.Flush()` calls would prevent this from happening.

How can I write to a file simultaneously from 2 different processes? If I write to a file simultaneously from 2 different threads within the SAME process, the writing occurs as expected (lots of alternating between threads).  But for 2 different processes, whichever one is started first does all of its writing, and then the other one goes.  Why is this?